# Apktool error when recompiles: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'allowNativeHeapPointerTagging' in package 'android'

Tags: apk, reverse-engineering, apktool, parrot-os

I'm trying to reverse an apk file using Parrot_os, but I receive this error. I manage to decompile and recompile the file only if I use "apktool d -r file.apk". Unfortunately, when I use -r parameter, I can't read AndroidManifest.xml and so I can't change the source code. Is there a solution?

This is the error:

```
44: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'allowNativeHeapPointerTagging' in package 'android'
W: 
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [/tmp/brut_util_Jar_165091152994175457033171788375995351588.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 21, --target-sdk-version, 31, --version-code, 2580, --version-name, 2.5.8, --no-version-vectors, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL16710956284277395539.tmp, -e, /tmp/APKTOOL14749837641641484705.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /home/user_name/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /home/user_name/Desktop/apk-reverse/files_backup/file/res, -M, /home/user_name/Desktop/apk-reverse/files_backup/file/AndroidManifest.xml]
```

I tried to update apktool to v2.7.0, but it didn't work.

Comment: Apktool has only support for MacOS, Windows (x86/amd64) and Linux(x86/amd64). What CPU/computer is Parrot_OS installed on?

Comment: Have you tried the `--use-aapt2` option when building?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work even if I use "--use-aapt2" option and the error message is the same. Moreover, this is the CPU model: "Intel® Core™ i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz × 8"